# Getting fields names double quoted and separated by a coma when passed as *args to a psycopg2 connection

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2, upsert

## Context

I'm trying to update/insert a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database with the content of a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) using [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/).

I am iterating over the DataFrame rows because we [can't](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553) use the [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method while using an UPSERT statement.

### Short

What I'm trying to do is to expand the columns names and their values into an SQL query string with [starred expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for columns names and actual values.

Everything works fine, except for two tiny embarrassing details;

1. columns names and values are not separated by a comma but a space,
2. columns names are single quoted, hence the error.

---

## Code, details and error message:

Here is the piece of code I'm using;

```
# Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)
import pandas as pd # -- version 1.0.3
import psycopg2     # -- version 2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)

df = pd.DataFrame({'__col1__name_': [1],
  '__col3__name_': [2],
  '__col3__name_': ['three'],
  '__col4__name_': [4],
  '_col5_name_': [5],
  '_col6_name_': [6],
  '_col7_name_': [7.0],
  '_col8_name_': [8.0],
})

cols      = list(df.columns)
nCols     = len(cols)
name      = "tablename"
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Warning: ugly query here, but I want it as compact as possible
    # and I need to pass the table name as an argument because I'm actually running this 
    # in a for loop over some tables which may change in the future, so I don't want 
    # to patch the code much each time a column is renamed or added to the database.
    query = """
        INSERT INTO """+"schema.{}".format(name)+"""
        ("""+nCols*'%s '+""")
        VALUES ("""+nCols* '%s ' +""")
        ON CONFLICT (%s) DO UPDATE SET
        ("""+(nCols)*'%s '+""") = ("""+(nCols)*'%s '+""")
        WHERE %s = %s
        """
    with psycopg2.connect(**DB_PARAMS) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as curs:
            print(curs.mogrify(sql_query, ((*cols, *row, cols[0], *cols, *row, cols[0], row[0]))))
            curs.execute(sql_query, ((*cols, *row, cols[0], *cols, *row, cols[0], row[0])))
```

And I get this `SyntaxError`:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'__col1__name_'"
LINE 3:         ('__col1__name_' '__col3__name_' '__col4__name_' '_c..
                 ^
```

I've got the same error if I copy paste the `mogrify` output directly into [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) for example.

Mogrify output is as follow:

```
INSERT INTO schema.tablename
        ('__col1__name_' '__col3__name_' '__col4__name_' '_col5_name_' '_col6_name_' '_col7_name_' '_col8_name_' )
        VALUES (1 'three' 4 5 6 7.0 8.0 )
        ON CONFLICT ('__col1__name_') DO UPDATE SET
        ('__col1__name_' '__col3__name_' '__col4__name_' '_col5_name_' '_col6_name_' '_col7_name_' '_col8_name_' ) = (1 'three' 4 5 6 7.0 8.0 )
        WHERE '__col1__name_' = 1
```

This doesn't work in Postgres because of the single quote.

I really try not to compose an SQL query string with `.format()` (except for the table name) prior to send it to `curs.execute()` but rather let `psycopg2` handle the arguments for me, which I've been told is a good idea.

---

## Question

How could I get the column names double-quoted and separated by a coma?
Same thing for the values; they are not coma separated.

Comment: just an observation : isnt this going to be slow?

Comment: Undoubtedly, yes. I would like to avoid the loop in a second time, so I'm totally open to faster solutions, but I prefer to keep the focus on one thing per question. I wish pandas `.to_sql()` could do that but it currently does not.

Comment: @s.k how about doing a `pd.to_sql` to a dummy_table, then use the update query to update your main table using the dummy table, then drop the dummy table.

Comment: I was actually thinking of that as a "workaround" (probably the best one) even if I feel it's not a perfect solution. But it may work indeed.